# Which stage of pipeline should I do culling and clipping and How should I reconstruct triangles after clipping

Tags: graphics, 3d, render

I'm trying to implement graphic pipeline in software level. I have some problems with clipping and culling now.

Basically, there are two main concerns:

1. When should back-face culling take place? Eye coordinate, clipping coordinate or window coordinate? I initially made culling process in eye coordinate, thinking this way could relieve the burden of clipping process since many back-facing vertices have already been discarded. But later I realized that in this way vertices need to take 2 matrix multiplications , namely left multiply model-view matrix --> culling --> left multiply perspective matrix, which increases the overhead to some extent.
2. How do I do clipping and reconstruct triangle? As far as I know, clipping happens in clipping coordinate(after perspective transformation), in another word homogeneous coordinate in which every vertex is being determined whether no not it should be discarded  by comparing its x, y, z components with w component. So far so good, right? But after that I need to reconstruct those triangles which have one or two vertices been discarded. I googled that Liang-Barsky algorithm would be helpful in this case, but in clipping coordinate what clipping plane should I use? Should I just record clipped triangles and reconstruct them in NDC?

Any idea will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1)

Back-face culling can occur wherever you want.

On the 3dfx hardware, and probably the other cards that rasterised only, it was implemented in window coordinates. As you say that leaves you processing some vertices you don't ever use but you need to weigh that up against your other costs.

You can also cull in world coordinates; you know the location of the camera so you know a vector from the camera to the face — just go to any of the edge vertices. So you can test the dot product of that against the normal.

When I was implementing a software rasteriser for a z80-based micro I went a step beyond that and transformed the camera into model space. So you get the inverse of the model matrix (which was cheap in this case because they were guaranteed to be orthonormal, so the transpose would do), apply that to the camera and then cull from there. It's still a vector difference and a dot product but if you're using the surface normals only for culling then it saves having to transform each and every one of them for the benefit of the camera. For that particular renderer I was then able to work forward from which faces are visible to determine which vertices are visible and transform only those to window coordinates.

(2)

A variant on Sutherland-Cohen is the thing I remember seeing most often. You'd do a forward scan around the outside of the polygon checking each edge in turn and adjusting appropriately.

So e.g. you start with the convex polygon between points (V1, V2, V3). For each clipping plane in turn you'd do something like:

```
for(Vn in input vertices)
{
    if(Vn is on the good side of the plane)
        add Vn to output vertices

    if(edge from Vn to Vn+1 intersects plane) // or from Vn to 0 if this is the last edge
    {
        find point of intersection, I
        add I to output vertices
    }
}
```

And repeat for each plane. If you're worried about repeated costs then you either need to adopt a structure with an extra level of indirection between faces and edges or just keep a cache. You'd probably do something like dash round the vertices once marking them as in or out, then cache the point of intersection per edge, looked up via the key (v1, v2). If you've set yourself up with the extra level of indirection then store the result in the edge object.

Comment: Thank you for @Tommy your advice. so when do you do the Sutherland-Cohen test and compute intersection of edge and plane? clipping coordinate? Say a triangle TriA(v0, v1, v2) is in clipping coordinate, and I compare every vertex's x,y,z with its w value, and it turns out that v1, v2 should be discarded. Here comes problem, I should I do after this? mark the triangle and computer intersection of edge01 and edge02 to some plane?

Comment: Again there's a variety of answers, I guess, but I personally usually clip after the transform into camera space, to remove `x > z`, `y < -z`, `z < 1`, etc. so you pay for that transform but not for projection. On a really small system that's good because it leaves you paying for some multiplications but avoiding some redundant divides, which of course are disproportionately expensive on old hardware.